# Extracting day, month, years and hours using laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I have a small problem in my laravel application. In my blade file, I would like to extract data from timestamp sql query result like using twig filter in Symfony.

Here is what I would like to do (here I used twig filter syntax)

```
<div class="day">{{ $post->published_at|date("d") }}</div>
<div class="month">{{ $post->published_at|date("m") }}</div>
```

How to do the samething in Larave blade file ?
Note that I tried to use the syntaxe below but it is not working for me

```
<div class="day">{{ $post->published_at->format('d') }}</div>
<div class="month">{{ $post->published_at->format('M') }}</div>
```

My project used laravel 8.

Is there somoene can help me please.

Comment: what's the problem with `format`?

Comment: When I use format, my browser tab refresh infinitely. I don't know if this issue is from my live server ?

Comment: I have deactivated my live server and now I get an error message like this: Error
Call to a member function format() on string (View: F:\wamp64\www\pride-express\resources\views\livewire\show-travel.blade.php)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/reservation?page=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Carbon.Here i assume your `published_at` format in db is `timestamp` or `datetime`

```
 Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->published_at)->format('d')
```

As suggested by Alberto Sinigaglia in comment,If you cast `published_at` in your model like below then you can easily format without manually parsing.

In your model

```
  protected $casts = [
        'published_at'=>'date'  // or datetime
    ];
```

then in your view

```
{{$post->published_at->format('d')}}
```

Comment: I would suggest just to add "$cast = ['published_at' => 'date']" in the model

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia.thanks for reminding.updated in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime` and `date` functions:

```
<?php
$time = strtotime($post->created_at);
$day = date('D', $time);
?>

<div class="day">{{ $day }}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked but there is some aspect that I don't understand. Why did I have to resort to using the strtotime function?

Comment: @crazy4dev. `strtotime()` function parses an English textual datetime into a Unix timestamp.

Comment: @crazy4dev. You can also use the carbon package to work with dates and times. https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: @crazy4dev, If you solved your problem by this answer, So accept and vote up please.

Comment: Upvote system is usefull to make best answer visible by other users. I have upvote your answer since yesterday but unfortinatelly I don't have yet the autorization for the vote.